# Print the MAC addresses from the mac header of IEEE802.11 packet when extracted using sk_buff

Tags: mac-address, printk

I am writing a module that extracts the MAC address of the Ethernet Mac header of wireless 802.11 packet. I extract the ethernetmac  header as

```
ieee = (struct ieee80211_hdr *)skb_mac_header(sock_buff);
ieee->addr1[ETH_ALEN];
ieee->addr2[ETH_ALEN];
ieee->addr3[ETH_ALEN];
```

I want to print these addresses to see the values it contains. How do I do that using `printk` and `KERN_INFO`

Currently i am using this statement but it causes kernel in panic mode

```
printk(KERN_INFO "The address is %x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", ieee->addr1[0],ieee->addr1[1],ieee->addr1[2],ieee->addr1[3],ieee->addr1[4],ieee->addr1[5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, according to [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/staging/rtl8712/ieee80211.h#L144), addr1 is u8 addr1[ETH_LEN], so:

```
printk("MAC %pM: \n", ieee->addr1);
```

Comment: Noops, kernel again went under panic mode

Comment: are you completely sure it panics on printk() call? check if it's not NULL.

Comment: Yes, if I comment it out the kernel does not panic,but if I do write a statement that prints a variable value like this address the kernel panics. Also it does not panic if i use printk only to print some statement. I checked it this address is null, and its not null. What can be the problem?

Comment: And also i just initialized an int i =9; and printed it, and it worked fine without panic and gave correct value of i variable